# iOS UIScrollView without user interaction and programmatic scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll, user-interaction

Is it possible to have a UIScrollView without the user being able to scroll and therefore is it possible to scroll a UIScrollView programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use these methods to scroll programmatically:

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated
- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated
```

You may also set `userInteractionEnabled=NO` to disable user touching events.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
-(void)scrollViewProgramatically
{
        UIScrollView *scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 250, 150)];
        scrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
        scrollview.scrollEnabled=YES;
        scrollview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        scrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1250,250);
        [scrollview addSubview:scrollview];
}
```